# shell script to reading from file and do depending on the pattern

Tags: shell, unix, loops, scripting, if-statement

Need advice on shell script to read the file and echo depending on the pattern

```
 cat revs.txt
 1
 3
 8:13
 18:71
 89


  if x:x then echo "This is revs range"
   else 
  echo " this is single rev"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
while read rev
do
    case "$rev" in
    (*:*) echo "This is a range of revisions $rev";;
    (*)   echo "This is a single revision $rev";;
    esac
done < revs.txt
```

Comment: +1. for bash, you'd write an "if" condition like this: `[[ $rev == *:* ]]`